# How can I convert a dict of arrays into a 'flattened' dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Let's say I had a dictionary of arrays, eg:

```
favourite_icecreams = {
    'Josh': ['vanilla', 'banana'],
    'Greg': ['chocolate'],
    'Sarah': ['mint', 'vanilla', 'mango']
}
```

I want to convert it to a pandas dataframe, with columns as "Flavour" and "Person". It should look like this:

| Flavour | Person |
| --- | --- |
| vanilla | Josh |
| banana | Josh |
| chocolate | Greg |
| mint | Sarah |
| vanilla | Sarah |
| mango | Sarah |

What's the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: just a typo, my bad! @sammywemmy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution, using `.explode()`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Person": favourite_icecreams.keys(),
        "Flavour": favourite_icecreams.values(),
    }
).explode("Flavour")


print(df)
```

Prints:

```
   Person    Flavour
0    Josh    vanilla
0    Josh     banana
1    Greg  chocolate
2   Sarah       mint
2   Sarah    vanilla
2   Sarah      mango
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use (generator) comprehension and then feed it to `pd.DataFrame`:

```py
import pandas as pd

favourite_icecreams = {
    'Josh': ['vanilla', 'banana'],
    'Greg': ['chocolate'],
    'Sarah': ['mint', 'vanilla', 'mango']
}

data = ((flavour, person)
            for person, flavours in favourite_icecreams.items()
            for flavour in flavours)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=('Flavour', 'Person'))

print(df)
     # Flavour Person
# 0    vanilla   Josh
# 1     banana   Josh
# 2  chocolate   Greg
# 3       mint  Sarah
# 4    vanilla  Sarah
# 5      mango  Sarah
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this purely in pandas like below using [`DataFrame.from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) and [`df.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
In [453]: df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(favourite_icecreams, orient='index').stack().reset_index().drop('level_1', 1)

In [455]: df.columns = ['Person', 'Flavour']

In [456]: df
Out[456]: 
  Person    Flavour
0   Josh    vanilla
1   Josh     banana
2   Greg  chocolate
3  Sarah       mint
4  Sarah    vanilla
5  Sarah      mango
```

Comment: speed wise I'd expect the other solution to be faster as the data size increases ... but you never know

Answer (score 1):

One option is to extract person and flavour into separate lists, use numpy repeat on the `person` list, and finally create the DataFrame:

```py
from itertools import chain
person, flavour = zip(*favourite_icecreams.items())
lengths = list(map(len, flavour))
person = np.array(person).repeat(lengths)
flavour = chain.from_iterable(flavour)
pd.DataFrame({'person':person, 'flavour':flavour})

  person    flavour
0   Josh    vanilla
1   Josh     banana
2   Greg  chocolate
3  Sarah       mint
4  Sarah    vanilla
5  Sarah      mango
```